# vim NERDTree shortcut to an existing function

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want to use the right-arrow key to open a node in NERDtree.  I see there is NERDTreeAddKeyMap, but I'm too much of a vimscript newb to know how to invoke it properly.  I want right-arrow to invoke activateNode.  I've done it by adding this line into NERD_tree.vim itself:

```
exec "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <Right> :call <SID>activateNode(0)<cr>"
```

but I want to do it the right way in my .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

`:help NERDTreeAddKeyMap()` will show you how to write a small plugin for NERDTree. Because you are calling a built-in NERDTree function you don't even need a custom one.

Comment: I was hoping for more detail here... I know nothing about vimscript.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, barring a limitation in the version I'm using (4.2.0), the following will do what you want.

In a mymapping.vim, in ~/.vimfiles/nerdtree_plugin/

```
" -*- vim -*-
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({ 'key': "Right", 'scope': "Node", 'callback': "<SID>activateNode" })
```

Now, to get "Right" to work properly, you'll have to edit NERD_tree.vim, in:

```
"FUNCTION: KeyMap.bind() {{{3
function! s:KeyMap.bind()
```

Change:

`if mapkey =~? '^\([CM]-\|middlerelease\|2-leftmouse\|leftrelease\)'`

to:

`if mapkey =~? '^\([CM]-\|middlerelease\|2-leftmouse\|leftrelease\|right\)'`

The old code didn't do special handling for mapping keys that weren't
<MiddleRelease>, <2-LeftMouse>, or <LeftRelease>

Comment: Probably should add that I don't think that you can do it "in your .vimrc" exactly.  Because the mapping depends on the plugin being loaded, I think the only way to do it is in a separate file like I outline above.